# I want to have folder dialogue path

Tags: excel, vba

I want user to pick folder of their choice, user input dialogue box in which i can choose the path.

```
 Sub Getsheets()

Path = "D:\Workbooks\" 'want to add the user choice path, rest of code is fine
Filename = Dir(Path & ("*.csv"))

Do While Filename <> ""


 Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

     Sheet.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Next Sheet
     Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is achieved easily using `Application.FileDialog` with the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` option (which restricts it to selecting folders).

A simply example is:

```
Sub Getsheets()
    Dim Path As String
    Path = ""

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then
            Path = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With

    If Path <> "" Then
        Filename = Dir(Path & ("\*.csv"))
        Do While Filename <> ""
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & "\" & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
            For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                Sheet.Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            Next Sheet
            Workbooks(Filename).Close
            Filename = Dir()
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

This code actually opens the folder dialog and only populates `Path` if `OK` is pressed (`.Show = -1`):

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show = -1 Then
        Path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
```

There is a check for whether the path is selected `Path <> ""`.

One final minor change, the path does not include an ending backslash so this is appended:

```
Filename = Dir(Path & ("\*.csv"))
```

**EDIT Following OP comment**

There was an error on the line where the Workbook.Open method is invoked due to the `Path` not ending with a backslash. The fixed line is:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & "\" & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
```

Comment: Actually its giving an error when im giving the folder path "Sorry we couldnt find "filepath"" actually im importing all the workbooks in single workbook in different tabs, so im giving the folder path in which all workbooks are present

Comment: @AftabKhan This is because the line `Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True` also needs a backslash character in it.  I'll amend the answer to reflect that